# Java convert between two timezones output incorrect result when using EEST timezone

Tags: java

I've been trying to convert between Asia/Riyadh to Asia/Amman as a test and the time should still the same as an example, you can check it right here : https://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/converter.html?iso=20200630T170000&p1=776&p2=214&p3=34&p4=11

[image: times]

this code :

```
String time = "20:00";
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("kk:mm");
formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Riyadh"));
Date date = formatter.parse(time);

SimpleDateFormat formatter2 = new SimpleDateFormat("kk:mm");
formatter2.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Dubai"));

System.out.println(formatter2.format(date));
```

will output a correct result, from `Riyadh` to `Dubai` will be `21:00`
but when i try to do it with `Amman` or `Beirut` the result is incorrect, the time should remain `20:00`, but it comes `19:00` is it something to do with `EEST` time zones?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any reason why you aren't using [date-time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)?

Comment: @Abra can you show me an example for my case ?

Comment: @Someone was below answer helpful?

Comment: @tryingToLearn was helpful as a reference, yes, now im trying to make the final code

Comment: @Someone, it think DST is not taken into account in your code. As Beirut/Amman is have DST saving.

Comment: @ihimanshu19 correct, is there a way to solve it using the same library? i used another one to solve this, i posted an answer

Comment: Yes you can create two different timezone same way you are doing then, creating calendar instance to get time. If you want I can provide the code for the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you print `date` you will see that the date is **Jan 1, 1970** and the time zones where different back then.

Change the code to ensure that the date is Jun 30, 2020.

*Showing the problem*

```java
String time = "20:00";
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("kk:mm");
formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Riyadh"));
Date date = formatter.parse(time);
System.out.println(date);
```

*Output*

```
Thu Jan 01 12:00:00 EST 1970
```

*Fixed using old `Date` API*

```java
String time = "6/30/2020 20:00";

SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("M/d/y kk:mm");
formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Riyadh"));
Date date = formatter.parse(time);
System.out.println(date);

SimpleDateFormat formatter2 = new SimpleDateFormat("M/d/y kk:mm z Z");
formatter2.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Riyadh"));
System.out.println(formatter2.format(date));

formatter2.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Dubai"));
System.out.println(formatter2.format(date));

formatter2.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Beirut"));
System.out.println(formatter2.format(date));

formatter2.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Amman"));
System.out.println(formatter2.format(date));
```

*Output*

```
Tue Jun 30 13:00:00 EDT 2020
6/30/2020 20:00 AST +0300
6/30/2020 21:00 GST +0400
6/30/2020 20:00 EEST +0300
6/30/2020 20:00 EEST +0300
```

*Fixed using newer Java 8 Time API*

```java
DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("M/d/u kk:mm");
fmt = fmt.withZone(ZoneId.of("Asia/Riyadh"));
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse(time, fmt);
System.out.println(zdt);

DateTimeFormatter fmt2 = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("M/d/u kk:mm z Z");
System.out.println(zdt.format(fmt2.withZone(ZoneId.of("Asia/Riyadh"))));
System.out.println(zdt.format(fmt2.withZone(ZoneId.of("Asia/Dubai"))));
System.out.println(zdt.format(fmt2.withZone(ZoneId.of("Asia/Beirut"))));
System.out.println(zdt.format(fmt2.withZone(ZoneId.of("Asia/Amman"))));
```

*Output*

```
2020-06-30T20:00+03:00[Asia/Riyadh]
6/30/2020 20:00 AST +0300
6/30/2020 21:00 GST +0400
6/30/2020 20:00 EEST +0300
6/30/2020 20:00 EEST +0300
```

Comment: i used another library to solve it, but i will try this out

Comment: @Someone if you have solved your problem on your own, then perhaps you could [answer your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) and share your solution with the community?

Comment: @Abra correct, but Anderas solution was much better